# Blender won't open on Linux 16.04

Tags: python

Blender 2.83 was working just fine. then over night the shortcut to open blender stopped working. after updating to blender 2.90 it stopped working completely.

I opened Blender via command prompts to check the error, and this is what i got

```
found bundled python: /snap/blender/45/2.90/python
GPUShader: linking error:
error: Input block `ShaderStageInterface' is not an output of the previous stage

GPUShader: linking error:
error: Input block `ShaderStageInterface' is not an output of the previous stage

Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please check that you hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.9x. Try to update the graphics driver for your GPU. I would also suggest you try the [Blender version for Linux](https://www.blender.org/download/) that is not a snap package, just in case the snap package is broken.

Comment: I'd recommend to use the versions from blender.org directly and not use repos, snap or flatpack. THose packages are compiled by third parties and might not work so well. There is no need to "install" blender, just download and decompress the file and run it from the folder where you decompressed it. As for assigning shortcuts or make files open with a specific app... any decent linux user should know how to do that.

Comment: My hardware supports. And also I downloaded the compressed blender files, 2.90 still doesn't open but 2.80 does.  I updated every driver, I only have a CPU. Which is strange that i see GPU on the error report. Everything was working perfectly up until it stopped opening from the shortcut, (by that time I hadn't updated my drivers)  then updated my drivers (still nothing).  then I decided to update to Blender 2.90 then that was the end of it.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. For now I will stick to Blender 2.83 ... which is fortunately a LTS Version. Older Blender versions can be downloaded [here](https://download.blender.org/release/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first what do you mean with 'linux 16.04'? You mean ubuntu 16.04? There are lot's of linux distros and they're all different. I don't think it's possible to use the latest GPU drivers on ubuntu 16.04, because that ubuntu version is more than 4 years old. On the other hand I can tell you from experience that the latest intel drivers in ubuntu 20.04 don't run Blender, I had to downgrade the driver. But I did get Blender 2.90 working on ubuntu 20.04 with intel graphics, so it *should* be possible.
- You say you don't have a GPU, but obviously you have, or you wouldn't see anything on you monitor  ;-) (GPU means Graphics Processing Unit, another word for graphics card). Maybe you mean you only have the GPU that's integrated in your motherboard? (Probably intel?).

You could try to run ubuntu 20.04 from an usb stick without installing it to test if it will run blender 2.90. If it does you could consider upgrading operating system.

I'm sorry this is not really an answer. I'd need more information to really help you. I'd have liekd to ask for extra information in a comment, but for 'reasons' it *is* possible to post an answer when you're new to this site, but not to post comments. Anyway. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated mesa via PPA and the error was gone:

---

1. Open terminal either via <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> or by searching for ‘Terminal’ from software launcher. When it opens, run command:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`

Type your password (no asterisks while typing due to security reason) when it prompts and hit Enter to continue.

2. After adding the PPA, do system update via command:

   `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

---

Link with instructions found here:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/06/install-mesa-18-1-1-ppa-ubuntu-18-04/